# Visible list item

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, loops, foreach

I am using a list to display a menu and trying to restrict menu items to certain users.

Example here is my menu:

```
<ul>
    <li id="link1" runat="server">Link 1</li>
    <li id="link2" runat="server">Link 1</li>
    <li id="link3" runat="server">Link 1</li>
</ul>
```

I can easily write something like:

```
if(User == "") {

    link1.Visible = false;
    link2.Visible = false;
}
link3.Visible = true;
```

But I want to use a loop to reference the list item ids in an array.
I am trying to make this code work: So that it should read
`link1.Visible = ... link2.Visible = ...` but I cannot use `link.Visible` in that way. How can I make this work?

Many thanks

```
ArrayList links = bw.return_arr_qry("Links", "BW_AppPerms", "Ext_App = 1");

// Links array return "link1", "link2", "link3" etc...

foreach(string link in links)
{
    if (BW_Access.accessApp(link, "Read") == false)
    {
        link.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to set the `Visible` property of the `string link` variable, this is obviously not possible. You have to use the actual web controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `runat="server"` to your `ul` like this `<ul runat="server" id="links">` then:

```
var Links = links.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>().ToArray();
foreach (HtmlGenericControl li in Links)
{
    if (BW_Access.accessApp(li, "Read") == false)
    {
        li.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Or use this if you don't want to use LINQ version:

```
foreach (Control li in links.Controls)
{
    if (li is HtmlGenericControl)
        li.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I am getting Arraylist does not have a definition for controls

Comment: @KarimAli Add this `using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;` to your `using` directives.

Comment: @KarimAli And also this `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @KarimAli This is a working answer. I'm sure if you have added this two using to your using directive at the top of your page in C# it should works exactly as you want. Probably you missed something here.

Comment: @KarimAli See my updated answer. Also there was a typo when you checked my answer. I changed `if (BW_Access.accessApp(link, "Read") == false)` to `if (BW_Access.accessApp(li, "Read") == false)`

Comment: @KarimAli Also don't forget that `links.Controls` links here refers to `ui` element.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get to you sooner. I did everything included in your answer and I am sure I didn't miss anything. The problem is with:

Comment: var Links = links.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>().ToArray();

Comment: System.Array does not contain a definition for controls. I am using both directives but this error persists.

Comment: @KarimAli As I said **links** here refers to ui element not the ArrayList that you have created already.

Comment: @KarimAli This is *links* : `<ul runat="server" id="links">
    <li id="link1" runat="server">Link 1</li>
    <li id="link2" runat="server">Link 1</li>
    <li id="link3" runat="server">Link 1</li>
</ul>`

Comment: I understand thanks got that bit working! So It should really be if (BW_Access.accessApp(li.ID, "Read") == false) however when this returns as true visibility for all items is hidden? I assume I need something like li.ID.Visible = false; but this is not valid. thanks for your help

Comment: Sure I will do that but it's not yet resolved. If the if statement is true it sets visibility for ALL items to false?

Comment: All I am trying to accomplish is .. if (BW_Access.accessApp(li.ID, "Read") == false) then I want to set THAT li.ID visibility to false. Can I do this?

Comment: This Code: `if (BW_Access.accessApp(li, "Read") == false)
    {
        li.Visible = false;
    } else {li.Visible = true;}`

Comment: I can't use (li, "Read") as the first parameter takes in a string. li.ID is what I need.

Comment: I am now taking it as htmlgeneric control like to thank you for help it's working!

Comment: can't see option for that